# does as3 support loop label?

Tags: actionscript-3, loops, label

I have a herarchery of loop and want to quit all parent loop, do AS3 support labels like we have them in php ?

```
for(var i:int=0;i<100;i++)
{
    for(var j:int=0;j<100;j++)
    {
        if(j == 15){

           i = 99;
           break;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use `label:` in front of the loop like this:

```
// Label this loop 'outer'.
outer: for(var i:int = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    inner: for(var j:int = 0; j < 100; j++)
    {
        if(j === 15)
        {
            // Break the outer loop.
            break outer;
        }
    }
}
```

This also works for `continue`.

Answer (score 0):

You could incorporate the break_condition into the for loop as well

```
var outer_break = false;
var inner_break = false;
for(var i = 0; i < 100 && !outer_break; i++) {
     for(var j = 0; j < 100 && !inner_break;j++) {
         if (some_condition) inner_break = true;
     }
}
```

I would recommend NOT to use labels (much to much goto) here and I would also strongly suggest not to use for loops at all. but instead use foreach to iterate over whatever you need to iterate.

Comment: This is actually the strategy I use too, but for its flexibility. Can you provide some reasons why you've recommended against using labels for loops? I'm interested in the downsides :)

Comment: Generally - "for loops with counters" are a smell for highly procedural/imperative code. using "gotos" (even in the form of labels) makes for some highly brittle code. if you can and performance isnt absolutely critical I strongly suggest to go for a more declarative/functional approach and use Array filter, forEach and map. Its simply the experience of 30 years of coding ;-)

Comment: I see. Like I said, I agree with and use this method - not sure how implying that I'm many years less experienced than you is adding anything useful.

Comment: Hi Marty,I didnt want to imply anything in regards to your age.It was rather the lack of hard empirical data, missing reports and studies on that topic that made me fall back on my personal (and subjective) experience of 30 years of programming and probably as many languages.