# Actions Script 3 Listener Without Function

Tags: actionscript-3, while-loop, listener, break

Question:

Is there a way to use a on-click listener without calling a function? I only started actions script yesterday so please excuse if my question does seem naive.

Reason For Question:

I am hoping to break out of a while-loop when MouseEvent.OnClick happens. The problem is when using a function in the Listener function it only breaks out of the function defined for itself and not the while-loop I am stuck in.

```
function PlayGame():Void {
    while (true) {
        OnAndOff.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK):void{ //Removed the ,function part
            PowerButton.Switch();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Crabar is right and you should not put your logic inside such infinite loop. However, just to let you know that you can label your loops in actionscript 3. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15780167/does-as3-support-loop-label

Comment: Yeah first thing a beginner needs to know is how to label loops ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a best way is to use infinite loop in as3, cause as3 has single thread. It mean that application will freezed when you will start your infinite loop. AS3 has event-based architecture so any user interaction dispatches some events.

If you need to call `PowerButton.Switch()` when user clicks on OnAndOff just call it in event handler:

```
OnAndOff.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onOnAndOffClick); // somewhere on initialize   

function onOnAndOffClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
    PowerButton.Switch();
}
```

If you need to use approach similar to infinite loop you can use ENTER_FRAME event:

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, someFunction);

function someFunction(event:Event):void {  // this function will be called automatically on each frame
    // some code...
}
```

Comment: Well I want the program to freeze. The point is not the Switch() statement but rather the While {break;} because it is suppose to simulate a "Off" state. Pressing the button will break it from the while and start the program. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Your program will not receive events when it has freezed. You can disable application (or any sprite) by controlling "enabled" property.

Comment: po is not just new to as3, he's new to programming. Answer voted down as well, the idea that infinite loop is a problem only on single threaded technology is misguided, infinite loop freeze and crash apps with any technology.

Comment: @BotMaster I do not see the need for this comment. I have been programming in C, C# Java, Javascript, Delphi,SQL, Python, Matlab, LUA and assembly now for a years now. The code I am trying to implement is a adaptation I did for a micro controller Frogger game which I used the same technique (C programming), where you are able to wait for a input inside a while loop. Just because you do not think it is plausible does not mean it isn't.

Comment: What part of infinite loop don't you understand? it's a loop that never, ever ends, try it in C and see what happens.

Comment: @BotMaster Infinite loop is not good strategic in as3, but you are wrong in your opinion that it crash app in any language. For example, you could create infinite loop in Delphi in separate thread with some exit condition. And change some global flag in main thread.

Comment: 'with some exit condition' that's not virtually an infinite loop anymore. Will you say with some technology you can release apps containing TRUE infinite loops (no exit whatsover) without any consequences?

Comment: The question's author wrote about infinite loop with exit condition as can be seen from his code. His problem that he can't receive any event while loop is working.

Comment: @crabar, I understand what mean - in AS3 a infinte loop is not a good choice. And I will change it. But then is there another way to stop the entire program without having to enable and disable all. Maybe some sort of await or stop command? I'll search this on my own aswell but for now the question has been aswered thank you

Comment: No, you can't pause all application and tha unpause it. You can disable some parts of application or make it invisible or you can stop animation on movieclips. And thats all.